# Inserting a space every (x) JAVA, using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am wondering if this is possible with regex or should I just split it up into a char array and do a loop?

Insert a space every (x) characters (specified by user) into a string they have typed in.

For example: They have the string "oogabooga".

They first want to insert a space every 2 characters, they would get "oo ga bo og a".

then they restart the program and want to have a space every 4 characters, they would get "ooga boog a"

(Ive already got the code to work but can't input a int to a regex, how do I do that in particular?)

Thanks for the help. I have searched for quite a while now on this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will need a backreference in the replace section, with a regex like the below if you are using regex:

```
.{n}
```

where `n` is the number of characters, and replace with `$0`  (`$0` is the backreference and will refer to the match part).

```
String in = "oogabooga";
String val = "2";   // use 4 here to insert spaces every 4 characters
String result = in.replaceAll("(.{" + val + "})", "$1 ").trim();
System.out.println(result);
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/vn5cGh)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

I was trying to insert a int (contained in val) instead of a string, like you have, where you have typed + val +.

I assume how this works is that regex takes a string but then converts that number to a int so it can process it?

ps. Sorry about the poor explanation here, I'm new to programming.

Comment: @togglism It's jut that you need to pass a regex string to the function, so an int would actually need more work (to convert it to a string so it can be appended to another string).