# Replace Every 5th Character Of The Input (SPACES COUNT)

Tags: java

I am trying write a program that accept an input and present the input with every 5th character replaced with X (count spaces also). 
For example:
input: "hello my name is mario"
outpu: "hellX my Xame Xi maXio"

I only manage to replace specific letters, e.g every "m" letter.

Any help?

Comment: You could convert the string to an char-Array and iterate through it, while changing every 5th char via index

Comment: If we could see your code, we would be able to point out why it's not working like you intend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting a space every (x) JAVA, using regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335312/inserting-a-space-every-x-java-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for you:

```
String test = "hello my name is mario";

    String result = "";
    int c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        if (c++==5) {
            result += "X";
            c = 1;
        } else {
            result += test.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

Comment: why do (c++==5) and not (c%5==0)  ? is it faster?

Comment: I don't if it's faster but maybe human readable is better

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about which character is at each fifth position you could use a regex.

```
String input = "hello my name is mario";
String output = input.replaceAll("(....).", "$1X");
System.out.printf("input : %s%noutput: %s%n", input, output);
```

**output**

```
input : hello my name is mario
output: hellX my Xame Xs maXio
```

Comment: `(.{4}).` is much shorter :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I believe you agree with me, that in this case it doesn't matter if we match by `(....).` or by `(.{4}).`. ;-) Or did you meant something else which I overlook. (Maybe there was some overlapping between our posts.)

Comment: Nope. Your regex looks fine. I was just trying to *shorten* it :)

Comment: @TheLostMind That's how I understood it. ;-) I appreciate your comments. Any chance to learn something new should be embraced.